# su: permission denied despite being root in oracle container

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

Running an oracle container based on the [official dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles). Container is running on an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux 2) which is RHEL derivative, I am getting:

```
Configuring Oracle Listener.
su: cannot open session: Permission denied
Listener configuration failed. Check log '/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/netca_configure_out.log' for more details.
su: cannot open session: Permission denied
```

Container is started with:

```
docker run --name=oracledb -p 1521:1521  \
-e ORACLE_SID=XE -e ORACLE_PDB=foo -e ORACLE_PWD=bar \
oracle/database:18.4.0-x
```

By changing the entrypoint and dropping into the shell as a root, and executing `su oracle` indeed gives me permission denied. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was inappropriate settings in the `limits.conf`. Changing the run command to include the --ulimit option where the nofile was increased fixed the problem:

```
docker run --name=oracledb --ulimit nofile=1048576:1048576 \
-p 1521:1521  \
-e ORACLE_SID=XE -e ORACLE_PDB=foo -e ORACLE_PWD=bar \
oracle/database:18.4.0-x
```

Note the `--ulimit nofile=1048576:1048576`.

Answer (score 7):

I was playing with docker and oraclelinux:7-slim, to install an Oracle Database. After installing oracle-database-preinstall-19c package, I stopped being able to "su -" into oracle account. Many say its because of "nofile unlimited" in limits.conf, others say  to comment "session  include system-auth" line in /etc/pam.d/su (the last one works by the way). However, before I installed the package, the configuration was all the same and I was able to do "su - oracle". And even if I create a new user belonging to the same group "su -" works. So it had to be something that the package changed.

After some investigation I discovered that the packages installs "**oracle-database-preinstall-19c.conf**" in **/etc/security/limits.d/** and that file has all the oracle limits configuration. Because we are working with docker, you have to *comment the following line* in order to work:

**#oracle   hard   memlock    134217728**

Comment: Searched 3 hours for this!! Thank you

Comment: I assume the `/etc/security/limits.d/` file is inside the container. If the container isn't running due to `su` issue, how do I go about editing this file to comment the line containing `memlock`?

Comment: for version XE 18.4.0 it was a different line: `oracle   hard   nproc    16384`

(but many thx didn't know how long i would search for this without this hint)

Answer (score 0):

For those that still need to run Oracle 18 for some reason, you can add `--privileged` to the Docker command:

```bash
docker run --name oracle18 --privileged -p 1521:1521 -v /opt/oracle18/oradata:/opt/oracle/oradata -e ORACLE_PWD=abcd1234 container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:18.4.0-xe
```